# Fantasy YA/children's book, maybe 70s. Two brothers, one goes on a quest, one is disabled. White unicorn on the cover

Tags: story-identification, books

One brother needs to find 10 (?) things. The last (?) task involved a unicorn, and another involved a witch. The disabled brother (who was in a wheelchair) also has an adventure, with a girl.

My mum read it as a child (70s/80s) in the British Council Library but doesn't remember any more than what I've written here. It's probably a British book.